# Is there a way to store the items that are removed from jQuery.uniqueSort() in a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery script:

```
var greetingsArray = [
    "Hello, Debbie!",
    "Hello, Randy!",
    "Hello, Carl!" ,
    "Hello, Patrick!",
    "Hello, Susan!",
    "Hello, Susan!",
    "Hello, Carl!"
];

$.uniqueSort(greetingsArray);
```

Is there a way to get the items that were removed from the array? If so, how would it be used to display a message showing these values?

For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="greetings"></div>
```

I want to display removed duplicate greetings in that div element with the following jQuery script:

```
var greetingsRemoved = ...;
$("#id").html("Removed the following duplicate greetings: " + greetingsRemoved);
```

What can I put in place of ... to make that happen? I hope this is neither too difficult nor complicated.

Comment: Of course, though... you'll have to implement your own jQuery.uniqueSort method.

Comment: though... are you sure that method actually works for you? it supposedly doesn't work on arrays of strings/numbers... only arrays of dom elements.

Comment: There are many SO questions about finding all the elements in an array that are duplicated. Use one of those methods to fill in `greetingsRemoved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is probably a bad thing to use [jQuery.uniqueSort()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.uniqueSort/) for doing this because of the reason stated in its description within the API Documentation, for some reason, it works as intended as follows:

**Just testing: Do not use this example!**

```js
var greetingsArray = [
    "Hello, Debbie!",
    "Hello, Randy!",
    "Hello, Carl!" ,
    "Hello, Patrick!",
    "Hello, Susan!",
    "Hello, Susan!",
    "Hello, Carl!"
];

var sortedArray = greetingsArray.slice().sort();
var greetingsDuplicate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < greetingsArray.length - 1; i++) {
 if (sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i]) {
  greetingsDuplicate.push(sortedArray[i]);
 }
}

$("#duplicate").html("Duplicate Greetings: " + greetingsDuplicate.join(", "));

$.uniqueSort(greetingsArray);

$("#unique").html("Unique Greetings: " + greetingsArray.sort().join(", "));
```

```html
<div id="unique"></div>
<div id="duplicate"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, there is a better way to do this by implementing the methods derived from both answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array/9229932#9229932) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array/840808#840808) instead to more accurately display the results you desire.

**The Actual Answer**

```js
    var greetingsArray = [
        "Hello, Debbie!",
        "Hello, Randy!",
        "Hello, Carl!" ,
        "Hello, Patrick!",
        "Hello, Susan!",
        "Hello, Susan!",
        "Hello, Carl!"
    ];
    
    var greetingsUnique = [];
    
    $.each(greetingsArray, function(index, value){
        if($.inArray(value, greetingsUnique) === -1) greetingsUnique.push(value);
    });
    
    $("#unique").html("Unique Greetings: " + greetingsUnique.sort().join(", "));
    
    var sortedArray = greetingsArray.slice().sort();
    var greetingsDuplicate = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < greetingsArray.length - 1; i++) {
     if (sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i]) {
      greetingsDuplicate.push(sortedArray[i]);
     }
    }
    
    $("#duplicate").html("Duplicate Greetings: " + greetingsDuplicate.join(", "));
```

```html
<div id="unique"></div>
<div id="duplicate"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```